# How to remove only punctuation but leave accented letters?

Tags: java, string

I am trying to remove only the punctuation from my text data but leave the accented letters. I do not want to replace the accented letters with English equivalents. I cannot figure out how to adapt my existing code to allow for higher ascii characters.

```
    while (input.hasNext()){
        String phrase = input.nextLine();
        String[] words = phrase.split(" ");
        for(String word: words){
              String strippedInput = word.replaceAll("[^0-9a-zA-Z\\s]", ""); 
        }
     }
```

If original input is:
O sal, ou o sódio, também é contraindicado em pacientes hipotensos?

Expected output should be: 
O sal ou o sódio também é contraindicado em pacientes hipotensos

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Consider using [Unicode Categories](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop), as "A-Z" is very English-centric and doesn't even cope with accents as discovered.

For example, the following would replace everything, including punctuation, *except* "any letter, any language" (`\p{L}`) or ["whitespace"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html) (`\s`). If it is desired to keep digits, add them back in as additional exclusions.

```
replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\s]", "")
```

Here is [an ideone demo](http://ideone.com/gwIVQR).

Answer (score 4):

replace **a-zA-Z** in regex string with **\p{L}** (any kind of letter from any language)

```
while (input.hasNext()){
    String phrase = input.nextLine();
    String[] words = phrase.split(" ");
    for(String word: words){
          String strippedInput = word.replaceAll("[^0-9\\p{L}\\s]", ""); 
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this.

public class punctuationRemove {

//private static String punc = "[][(){},.;!?<>%]";
 static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 static char[] punc = "',.;!?(){}[]<>%".toCharArray();

 public static void main(String[] args){
        String s = "Hello!, how are you?";
        System.out.println(removePuntuation(s));
    }

 public static String removePuntuation(String s)
 {
     String tmp;
     boolean fl=true;

     for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
     {
         fl=true;
         char strChar=s.charAt(i);
         for (char badChar : punc) 
         {
            if (badChar == strChar)
            {
               fl=false;
               break;
             }
          }

          if(fl)
          {
             sb.append(strChar);
           }
     }
     return sb.toString();
 }
}
```

Comment: Good idea to use a char array for all necessary punctuation. Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't the for loop end condition just be i < s.Length()? If the string is 10 characters, indexing will go up to 9, but your loop will only go up to 8.

Comment: Sorry @McAdam331.Yeah its true!.It must be s.length(). Wondering how come I landed at s.length-1.Please update the correction.

Comment: No need to be sorry. I tried to edit for you, but Stack requires edits to be 6 characters. Indexing beginning at 0 can be so hard to follow at times. I mean, you could have even changed it to i <= s.Length() - 1, and then you would have a valid for loop again.

Comment: @McAdam331 Yeah true!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing the point, but something like...

```
String text = "O sal, ou o sódio, também é contraindicado em pacientes hipotensos?";
System.out.println(text);
System.out.println(text.replaceAll("[\\?,.:!\\(\\){}\\[\\]<>%]", ""));
```

Outputs

```
O sal, ou o sódio, também é contraindicado em pacientes hipotensos?
O sal ou o sódio também é contraindicado em pacientes hipotensos
```

Or, based on your example...

```
while (input.hasNext()){
    String phrase = input.nextLine();
    String[] words = phrase.split(" ");
    for(String word: words){
          String strippedInput = word.replaceAll("[\\?,.:!\\(\\){}\\[\\]<>%]", ""); 
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be inefficient, and I'm sure the idea can be improved upon, but you could create a method that loops through the string, building a buffer of each character that is not punctuation.

```
private String replacePunctuation(String s){
    String output = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < s.Length(); i++){
        if(s.charAt(i) != '.' && s.charAt(i) != ',' && s.charAt(i) != '!') // Add other punctuation values you're concerned about. Perhaps the Regex class would be useful here, but I am not as familiar with it as I would like.
            output += s.charAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Again, probably not the cleanest or most efficient, but it's the best I can come up with at the moment.