# Displacement of diacritics/accents from strings in python

Tags: python, string, nlp

I am working on a NLP task that requires using a corpus of the language called Yoruba. Yoruba is a language that has diacritics in its alphabets. If I read any text/corpus into the python environment, some of the upper diacritics gets displaced/shifted especially for alphabets ẹ and ọ:

[image: an image description]

for characters ẹ with diacritics at the top they get displaced. to have:ẹ́ ẹ̀  also for ọ the same thing occurs.( ọ́ ọ̀ )

```
def readCorpus(directory="news_sites.txt"):
with open(directory, 'r',encoding="utf8", errors='replace') as doc:
data = doc.readlines()
return data
```

The expected result is having the diacritics rightly placed at the top
(I am surprised stackoverflow was able to fix the diacritics).

Later the diacritics that have been displaced are seen as a punctuation and therefore removed (by my NLP processing function) thus affecting the whole task.

Comment: These are combining diacritics. SO has a first class Unicode renderer so it gets them right. But the various Python renderers aren't nearly so capable and so they don't combine the diacritics properly. The some will be true of most IDEs in whatever language. Paste your data into M S Word and it will probably also do the right thing. So the problem is not in your data, it is in your development environment's Unicode support.

Comment: @BoarGules, thanks for your response. So it is (nearly) impossible to fix this in python?? As the displacement affects the tokenization process.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings If possible refer this link and see, if you can use different encoding.

Comment: @Richa Thanks for the link. I found the codec for the language(Yoruba) to be ISO 639-3 from this page: https://iso639-3.sil.org/code_tables/639/read. I have tried using it in python the error I got is **unknown encoding: iso639_3**. Any clue or idea on how to go about this is welcome as iso639-3 is not in the python documentation.

Comment: For some of these, you might be able to fix it by using [the `unicodedata` module to `normalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) the text to `NFC` or `NFKC` form, which (when possible) replaces a character (often ASCII) followed by combining diacritics with a single non-ASCII character that incorporates the diacritics.

Comment: @JesujobaALABI: Don't bother with Yoruba specific ASCII superset encodings; if your input is UTF-8, keep using UTF-8. Nothing about this requires a language specific codec, and using one is a great way to cause problems/confusion down the line (because most one byte per character ASCII superset encodings are impossible to identify without analyzing each possible decoding by someone who speaks the language, as they'll all successfully decode, but most of them will produce gibberish).

Comment: @BoarGules: I wouldn't blame "Python renderers" here; Python is usually just dumping the text to the console, and it's up to the console to handle it. Windows's `cmd.exe` console is unusually terrible at Unicode, but many terminal programs (especially older ones with legacy compatibility constraints) tend to get combining diacritics wrong, and Python doesn't really have any control over that.

Comment: @ShadowRanger that's true, though I speak the language. The problem is that since it is an NLP task, the diacritics that has been displaced is seen as a punctuation which is therefore removed(my the processing function) and thus affecting the whole task.

Comment: @JesujobaALABI: If your filter is treating combining characters as punctuation, the solution is to fix your filter. Simple approach might be to take whatever you existing filter is, and add [a test for `unicodedata.combining(letter)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.combining); that returns `0` for non-combining characters (so if they're otherwise punctuation, you remove them), but non-`0` for combining characters (in which case you keep them). (Comment made here, not to comment on answer where you posted, because that answer is bad, and may be deleted)

Comment: @JesujobaALABI: Yes, but do you speak Russian? Arabic? Hebrew? Greek? Turkish? Thai? Korean? And does everyone who might eventually want to read your text? Will all your files include "encoded in iso639_3" in the file name? Because if not, you're making a headache for someone else down the line. UTF-8 may be slightly larger, but it's self-checking (random bytes are highly unlikely to produce valid UTF-8), and it's universal; no need to guess the language, just decode, and the correct characters fall out.

Comment: Between fixing your filter and/or converting to `NFC` form, one or both should fix your problem.

Comment: @dbc I am working on Colab. I also tried Jupyter notebook on my Linux mint Laptop. But on both platforms I got same result.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Python has complete control over what IDLE does and it can't even handle surrogate pairs.

Comment: The only workaround I can suggest is to not ask Python `print` calls to show your data, but instead create (for example) a PDF and display that. In other words, you need to ask some other program to render the Unicode, and display what it produces. A word processor, a PDF maker, something like that. My first choice would be to produce the PDF from Python using `reportlab` but it doesn't support combining diacritics either, so that is a non-starter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed numbers using reg ex 'cos some the strings contain numbers but used the maketrans method from the string library to remove the punctuation marks.

```
import string
out = re.sub(r'[0-9\.]+', '', ins)
punct = str.maketrans({k: None for k in string.punctuation})
new_s = out.translate(punct)
```

Comment: Note: You don't need to build the `dict` manually before passing to `str.maketrans`, you can just do `str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)` (the third argument is characters to be deleted in the translation table). Also note that this only handles ASCII punctuation, stuff like smart quotes (that many word processing tools substitute for ASCII single and double quotes automatically) aren't included in `string.punctuation`.

Answer (score 1):

As [noted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56869968/displacement-of-diacritics-accents-from-strings-in-python/56870497?noredirect=1#comment100289177_56869968), your text is correct, it's just being displayed wrong (your console, whatever it is, isn't Unicode-friendly, and doesn't handle Unicode combining characters properly).

Your real problem seems to be that [you're trying to do some processing to remove punctuation, and the combining diacritics are being seen as punctuation and removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56869968/displacement-of-diacritics-accents-from-strings-in-python/56870497?noredirect=1#comment100293953_56870497).

In your case, you've got multiple combining diacritics involved, and there is no single Unicode ordinal that represents all of them put together, so using `unicodedata.normalize('NFC', originalstring)` won't help you (it would combine one of the combining characters for `ọ́`, but not both).

So your only real solution is to fix your punctuation filter so it doesn't drop combining characters. This shouldn't be too hard, just change the filtering code from:

```
if is_punctuation(letter):  # is_punctuation is whatever test you're using to find punctuation
    # drop letter
else:
    # keep letter
```

to (after adding `import unicodedata` to the top of your file):

```
if is_punctuation(letter) and not unicodedata.combining(letter):
    # drop letter
else:
    # keep letter
```

[`unicodedata.combining` returns `0` for combining characters, non-`0` otherwise](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.combining), so you can use it to ensure combining characters aren't dropped, even if they count as punctuation by some other standard.

Comment: Thanks @ShadowRanger. This should work if each character is been  checked (though I feel it's going to be time consuming) but What happens if I am using regular expression for removing the punctuation?

Comment: The regular expression is: out = re.sub(r'[^\w\d\s]+', '', ins)

Comment: @JesujobaALABI: Depends how you're using the regex? `re.sub` allows you to pass an arbitrary function as the `repl` argument, so you could look for all the punctuation, and have the `repl` function you pass keep or discard it on the basis of a `unicodedata.combining` test. I'd recommend a full `def` function due to the complexity; don't try to one-line this into a `lambda`.

Comment: @JesujobaALABI - I'm no expert on regex but maybe [How to remove only punctuation but leave accented letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24878513) might help.  You might also need to retain combining characters explicitly by using the category `\p{M}`, and numbers with `\p{N}`.

Comment: I found a way around removing punctuation without removing the accents. Many thanks.